# How to re-enable backspace key in Javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, dom-events

I am using keypress event to disable backspace key when `<body contenteditable="true">` for selected text.
After selecting text the backspace key is disabled properly.
But, de-selecting text backspace key remain disabled. How do I re-enable backspace key in JavaScript?

**CODE:**

```
document.getElementById("cke_bdy").addEventListener("keypress", function(e) {
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (code === 46 || code === 8) {
        flag = false;
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Attach an onblur event to the textarea with the inverse of the code used to disable the backspace key.

If the backspace key is disabled by searching for the key's ID and calling preventDefault(), remove the listener within the onblur event.

Comment: No,it still disabled throughout

Comment: Ok new tactic. Create a variable that can be accessed within the addEventListener AND from two new simple functions attached to the onblur and onfocus events of the textarea. Set this new variable to false. Make onblur set the variable to true, and onfocus set the variable back to false. In the if( code ) statement add a check for your new variable. Add an else statement that contains 'return true', this should nullify preventDefault();